# Opnet creating simple two wireless nodes testing path loss

Tags: opnet

I am new to OPNET, i am tring to test the pathloss between two points using tirem wave function on a specific map

I use OPNET 15.0 and I have all the needed models

I want to know how to create two simple nodes and make them talk and see the path loss in that communication

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to define application traffic between nodes. Normally I would just open the object pallete and drop two 10BaseT_LAN models and an Application Config object to your workspace, then connect them with a 10BaseT model.  But you're using TIREM, so you might need to select wireless node and link types.  In the Application Config you define a traffic type (e.g. a constant bit rate FTP flow), then edit the attributes for a node model and assign that application definition to that node.

In order to plot path loss, select Collect DES Statistics DES / Choose Individual Statistics... (or right-click on a device or the workspace and select Choose Individual DES Statistics).

[image]

Then after select the loss statistic under the IP category, as shown here:

[image]

After you run a DES simulation, you should be able to plot the loss statistics under the DES results menu:

[image]
[image]